# Read audio file from video in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video-processing, audio-recording, multimedia

Can anyone tell me how I can read audio and video parts of video file as separate file ?
I need to have sampling rate and audio sample from a video file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for audio:

```
video.MultimediaFileReader(videofilename,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
```

and use this for video:

```
video.MultimediaFileReader(videofilename,'AudioOutputPort',false,'VideoOutputPort',true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. But how can I access the audio sample ? and How I can write the video again by using audio and video ?

Comment: you can use **video.MultimediaFileWriter(outputvideofilename, 'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',true)** to attched them again.

Comment: Please tell me how can I access audio samples ?

Comment: when I use audioFrame = step(hmfr); it just give me zero array ?!?

Comment: @amirnemat: Let me see your code?!

Comment: [filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.*'},'Video Selector');
fulpathname=strcat(pathname,filename);
hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(fulpathname,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
[VideoFrame,AudioFrame] = step(hmfr);
hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(fulpathname,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
while ~isDone(hmfr)
audioFrame = step(hmfr);
end
close(hmfr);

Comment: The problem is that audioFrame can not give me audio sample it just give me 0 -1 -12 10 ....